# How to access multidimensional arrays in Flutter Dart

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, dart, multidimensional-array

So I want to create a looping widget whose data comes from a data list in the form of JSON.
The JSON format looks like this:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200,
        "status": "success",
        "message": "Digital Cards successfully retrieved!"
    },
    "data": [
        {
            "indexs": "12",
            "apply_date": "2021-03-14",
            "id_member_card": "00",
            "name_member_card": "Card 1",
            "id_card": null,
            "id_card_design": null,
            "id_patner_card": null,
            "start_date": "2021-01-01",
            "end_date": "2050-12-31",
            "periode_month": "12",
            "min_trans_active": ".00",
            "max_month_active": "12",
            "min_trans_benefit": ".00",
            "max_month_benefit": "1",
            "allow_child_card": "1",
            "max_transfer_point": ".00",
            "expired_month": "12",
            "expired_trx_amount": ".00",
            "added_sp": "1",
            "added_point": "1",
            "flag_point": "0",
            "flag_status": "1",
            "recuser": "2071      ",
            "recdate": null,
            "recuserupd": "2071      ",
            "recdateupd": "2021-01-07 14:35:31.000",
            "image": null
        },
        {
            "indexs": "4",
            "apply_date": "2021-03-14",
            "id_member_card": "01",
            "name_member_card": "Card 2",
            "id_card": "PC",
            "id_card_design": "PC",
            "id_patner_card": null,
            "start_date": "2021-01-01",
            "end_date": "2050-12-31",
            "periode_month": "12",
            "min_trans_active": ".00",
            "max_month_active": "1",
            "min_trans_benefit": ".00",
            "max_month_benefit": "1",
            "allow_child_card": "0",
            "max_transfer_point": "10000.00",
            "expired_month": "12",
            "expired_trx_amount": "1.00",
            "added_sp": "1",
            "added_point": "1",
            "flag_point": "1",
            "flag_status": "1",
            "recuser": "2071      ",
            "recdate": "2017-02-10 14:53:51.000",
            "recuserupd": "CS01      ",
            "recdateupd": "2023-04-26 18:41:01.000",
            "image": "~/Content/Images/CardDesigns/platinum_card.png",
            "benefits": [
                {
                    "indexs": "1",
                    "id_member_card": "01",
                    "name_benefit": "Voucher 25.000",
                    "description": "Free voucher 25.000 ready to use",
                    "recuser": "2071",
                    "recdate": "2023-07-20 09:00:00.000",
                    "recuserupd": null,
                    "recdateupd": null
                },
                {
                    "indexs": "7",
                    "id_member_card": "01",
                    "name_benefit": "Voucher 50.000",
                    "description": "Free voucher 50.000 ready to use",
                    "recuser": "2071",
                    "recdate": "2023-07-20 09:00:00.000",
                    "recuserupd": null,
                    "recdateupd": null
                },
                {
                    "indexs": "8",
                    "id_member_card": "01",
                    "name_benefit": "Voucher 100.000",
                    "description": "Free voucher 100.000 ready to use",
                    "recuser": "2071",
                    "recdate": "2023-07-20 09:00:00.000",
                    "recuserupd": null,
                    "recdateupd": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I made a Model using [JSON Converter](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) and it looks like this:

```
class DigitalCardsModel extends Equatable {
  Meta? meta;
  List<Data>? data;

  DigitalCardsModel({this.meta, this.data});

  DigitalCardsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    meta = json['meta'] != null ? Meta.fromJson(json['meta']) : null;
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (meta != null) {
      data['meta'] = meta!.toJson();
    }
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [data];
}

class Meta {
  int? code;
  String? status;
  String? message;

  Meta({this.code, this.status, this.message});

  Meta.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['code'];
    status = json['status'];
    message = json['message'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['code'] = code;
    data['status'] = status;
    data['message'] = message;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? indexs;
  String? applyDate;
  String? idMemberCard;
  String? nameMemberCard;
  String? idCard;
  String? idCardDesign;
  String? idPatnerCard;
  String? startDate;
  String? endDate;
  String? periodeMonth;
  String? minTransActive;
  String? maxMonthActive;
  String? minTransBenefit;
  String? maxMonthBenefit;
  String? allowChildCard;
  String? maxTransferPoint;
  String? expiredMonth;
  String? expiredTrxAmount;
  String? addedSp;
  String? flagPoint;
  String? flagStatus;
  String? recuser;
  String? recdate;
  String? recuserupd;
  String? recdateupd;
  String? image;
  List<Benefits>? benefits;

  Data({
    this.indexs,
    this.applyDate,
    this.idMemberCard,
    this.nameMemberCard,
    this.idCard,
    this.idCardDesign,
    this.idPatnerCard,
    this.startDate,
    this.endDate,
    this.periodeMonth,
    this.minTransActive,
    this.maxMonthActive,
    this.minTransBenefit,
    this.maxMonthBenefit,
    this.allowChildCard,
    this.maxTransferPoint,
    this.expiredMonth,
    this.expiredTrxAmount,
    this.addedSp,
    this.flagPoint,
    this.flagStatus,
    this.recuser,
    this.recdate,
    this.recuserupd,
    this.recdateupd,
    this.image,
    this.benefits,
  });

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    indexs = json['indexs'];
    applyDate = json['apply_date'];
    idMemberCard = json['id_member_card'];
    nameMemberCard = json['name_member_card'];
    idCard = json['id_card'];
    idCardDesign = json['id_card_design'];
    idPatnerCard = json['id_patner_card'];
    startDate = json['start_date'];
    endDate = json['end_date'];
    periodeMonth = json['periode_month'];
    minTransActive = json['min_trans_active'];
    maxMonthActive = json['max_month_active'];
    minTransBenefit = json['min_trans_benefit'];
    maxMonthBenefit = json['max_month_benefit'];
    allowChildCard = json['allow_child_card'];
    maxTransferPoint = json['max_transfer_point'];
    expiredMonth = json['expired_month'];
    expiredTrxAmount = json['expired_trx_amount'];
    addedSp = json['added_sp'];
    flagPoint = json['flag_point'];
    flagStatus = json['flag_status'];
    recuser = json['recuser'];
    recdate = json['recdate'];
    recuserupd = json['recuserupd'];
    recdateupd = json['recdateupd'];
    image = json['image'];
    if (json['benefits'] != null) {
      benefits = <Benefits>[];
      json['benefits'].forEach((v) {
        benefits!.add(Benefits.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['indexs'] = indexs;
    data['apply_date'] = applyDate;
    data['id_member_card'] = idMemberCard;
    data['name_member_card'] = nameMemberCard;
    data['id_card'] = idCard;
    data['id_card_design'] = idCardDesign;
    data['id_patner_card'] = idPatnerCard;
    data['start_date'] = startDate;
    data['end_date'] = endDate;
    data['periode_month'] = periodeMonth;
    data['min_trans_active'] = minTransActive;
    data['max_month_active'] = maxMonthActive;
    data['min_trans_benefit'] = minTransBenefit;
    data['max_month_benefit'] = maxMonthBenefit;
    data['allow_child_card'] = allowChildCard;
    data['max_transfer_point'] = maxTransferPoint;
    data['expired_month'] = expiredMonth;
    data['expired_trx_amount'] = expiredTrxAmount;
    data['added_sp'] = addedSp;
    data['flag_point'] = flagPoint;
    data['flag_status'] = flagStatus;
    data['recuser'] = recuser;
    data['recdate'] = recdate;
    data['recuserupd'] = recuserupd;
    data['recdateupd'] = recdateupd;
    data['image'] = image;
    if (benefits != null) {
      data['benefits'] = benefits!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Benefits {
  String? indexs;
  String? idMemberCard;
  String? nameBenefit;
  String? description;
  String? recuser;
  String? recdate;
  String? recuserupd;
  String? recdateupd;

  Benefits({
    this.indexs,
    this.idMemberCard,
    this.nameBenefit,
    this.description,
    this.recuser,
    this.recdate,
    this.recuserupd,
    this.recdateupd,
  });

  Benefits.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    indexs = json['indexs'];
    idMemberCard = json['id_member_card'];
    nameBenefit = json['name_benefit'];
    description = json['description'];
    recuser = json['recuser'];
    recdate = json['recdate'];
    recuserupd = json['recuserupd'];
    recdateupd = json['recdateupd'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['indexs'] = indexs;
    data['id_member_card'] = idMemberCard;
    data['name_benefit'] = nameBenefit;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['recuser'] = recuser;
    data['recdate'] = recdate;
    data['recuserupd'] = recuserupd;
    data['recdateupd'] = recdateupd;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I've managed to access the `"data"` by using a Map like this:

```
AppBar(
  leading: header(),
  title: const Text('Digital Cards'),
  bottom: TabBar(
    tabs: state.data.data!.map(
      (Data val) {
        return Tab(
          text: '${val.nameMemberCard}',
        );
      },
    ).toList(),
  ),
)
```

But I need to access the `"benefits"` in the `"data"` shown in JSON.
So how to access `"benefits"`?
Should I use a `foreach` or `for` loop?
Can you use Maps like i use, above?

Please help, thank you..

Comment: yes, you can use `map` to repeat your `benefits`. what result do you expect?

Comment: Yeah i just dont understand how to use `map()` for nested array also using generated Model..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your Json response:

```
DigitalCardsModel model = await JsonResponseFromApi();
```

then use it like this:

```
//first builder for list of "data"
return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: model.data.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    var data = model.data;
    if (data[index].benefits != null) {
      //second builder for each data's list of benefits
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data.benefits.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
          return Text(data.benefits[idx].description);
        },
      );
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: Where does the `JsonResponseFromApi()` come from?

Comment: from your api call method

Comment: I don't understand.. Which one? Do you mean like this? `DigitalCardsModel model = DigitalCardsModel();` ?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data take a look at this example

Comment: Ok, i'll try it first if its suits my code needs, thanks